# Update Based on Select

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am attempting to update one column of a table based on data present in other records of the same table. All records either have the same date in the "CurrentDate" field or are null. I want to change those with null values to be the same as the rest of the fields.

Here is my code, but I am getting a syntax error:

```
Public Sub RiskVisual()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

---

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Hold3 SET CurrentDate = (SELECT CurrentDate FROM Hold3 LIMIT 1) WHERE CurrentDate IS NULL;"

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Sifu SQL Syntax differs depending on the DBMS

Comment: @user3780550 from the looks of it it you're just attempting to set the currentDate to null

Comment: If you are accessing a SQL Server backend, then the syntax you provided is incorrect and would result in an error.

Comment: This is VBA code in Access.

Comment: I think you're better off getting the value of `TOP 1 Hold3.CurrentDate` in a different manner, setting it to a variable, and using that variable in your update statement.

Comment: I figured that would be the best solution, though I can't seem to figure out how to store the result of that query as a variable that I can than access. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access the "TOP 1" works better than "LIMIT 1". You will also want to specify when seeking for the top 1 that the top 1 that is not null. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE Hold3 SET Hold3.CurrentDate = (SELECT TOP 1 Hold3.CurrentDate FROM Hold3 WHERE (((Hold3.CurrentDate) Is Not Null))) WHERE (((Hold3.CurrentDate) Is Null));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sean. Unfortunately, I had previously attempted this method and got Error 3073, saying that the "operation must be an updateable query," and I could not figure out why that might occur. Any ideas?